# What is CLSID? Is it a GUID?

Tags: c++, delphi, interface

What exactly is a CLSID data type? As it is used in C++, and I want to use it in [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A CLSID is a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) that identifies a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) object. In order to instantiate a registered COM object, you need to know its CLSID.

Typically in Delphi you would be calling `CoCreateInstance`. You simply call the function and pass a CLSID. The declaration of `CoCreateInstance` declares the class ID parameter as having type `TCLSID` which is a simple alias of `TGUID`. So pass one of those.

Here are the declarations, as lifted from the Delphi source:

```
type
  TCLSID = TGUID;

function CoCreateInstance(const clsid: TCLSID; unkOuter: IUnknown;
  dwClsContext: Longint; const iid: TIID; out pv): HResult; stdcall;
```

An example of a call to `CoCreateInstance`, taken from my code base:

```
const
  CLSID_WICImagingFactory: TGUID = '{CACAF262-9370-4615-A13B-9F5539DA4C0A}';

if not Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, ...)) then
  ...
```

You will likely be creating a different interface, and so will need to substitute the appropriate CLSID for that interface.

There is one other little trick that is worth knowing about. If you pass an interface type as a parameter of type `TGUID`, and that interface type has a GUID, then the compiler will substitute the GUID for you. So the above code could equally well be written:

```
type
  IWICImagingFactory = interface
    // this is the GUID of the interface, the CLSID
    [{ec5ec8a9-c395-4314-9c77-54d7a935ff70}]
    ....
  end;

....

if not Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(IWICImagingFactory, ...)) then
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this what I wanted to know, that CLSID is a GUID.

Comment: You could have discerned that by looking at the source. Does your Delphi edition come with source?

Comment: Yes it dose, but I couldn't find CLSID or TCLSID.

Comment: They are easy to find with a search using the IDE's Find in Files function. Or you can use CTRL+click on a symbol to find its definition. As much as its useful for you to know the answer, what will really help you is some tips on how to find the answers yourself!

Comment: oh, I found it using Find in Files, Thanks man you're the best.

Comment: I usually search in the help files that comes with Delphi, but didn't found it there, so I assumed that it is not in Delphi at all.

Comment: @user2896601: Don't assume. The "find declaraction" feature is quite helpful.

Answer (score 6):

> **What is a CLSID?** A Class ID (CLSID) is a 128 bit (large) number that represents a unique id for a software application or application
>   component. Typically they are displayed like this
>   "{AE7AB96B-FF5E-4dce-801E-14DF2C4CD681}".
>
> You can think of a CLSID as a "social security number" for a piece of
>   software, or a software component.
>
> **What are they used for?** CLSIDs are used by Windows to identify software components without having to know their "name". They can also
>   be used by software applications to identify a computer, file or other
>   item.
>
> **Where do they come from?** Microsoft provides a utility (program) called GUIDGEN.EXE that generates these numbers. They are generated by
>   using the current time, network adapter address (if present) and other
>   items in your computer so that no two numbers will ever be the same. [**[1]**](http://www.fileresearchcenter.com/showglossaryterm.html?term=CLSID)

and

> COM classes are named by CLSIDs, which are UUIDs as defined by OSF/DCE
>   RPC [**[2]**](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/clsid-scheme)

*<sub>Two quotes are cited</sub>*

Comment: so CLSID is the same as GUID?

Comment: Yes both try to make (pseudo) unique id. CLSID targets COM class objects.

Comment: It appears in "c" land you can pass CLSID's into methods that take GUID's (not sure about vice versa but probably)